# Prevent thread switches if no suspension happens in the call stack

Tags: swift, async-await, structured-concurrency

In a call chain of async methods, where none of the functions in the call stack suspend, how can we instruct the runtime not to do a thread switch?

Given the code below:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct MyApp: App {
    @StateObject var appCoordinator = AppCoordinator()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            EmptyView()
                .task {
                    await appCoordinator.start(settings: UserDefaults.standard)
                }
        }
    }
}

@MainActor
final class AppCoordinator: ObservableObject {
    func start(settings: Settings) async {
        try? await settings.write(bool: false, atKey: "isFirstRun")
    }
}

protocol Settings {
    func write(bool: Bool, atKey key: String) async throws
}

extension UserDefaults: Settings {
    func write(bool: Bool, atKey key: String) async throws {
        set(bool, forKey: key)
    }
}
```

, the following happen:

- the `.task` body calls the `appCoordinator.start()` function from the main thread (since the task inherits the current actor context)
- `appCoordinator` calls `settings.write` from the main thread (as `AppCoordinator` is `@MainActor`)
- however once the execution reaches the body of the `write(bool:atKey:)` function, the execution is moved to another thread.

I know that we should not make assumptions about on which thread the async functions execute, however for cases like this, the thread switch affects performance, and IMO is not needed. Even if an actor would've implement the protocol, its executor would've been the one that would ensure the atomicity of the actor's operations.

I could decorate the `write(bool:atKey:)` function with `@MainActor`, however that doesn't sound right.

I could also drop the `async` requirement over the protocol, however in the actual project, the `UserDefults` instance is injected via a protocol that needs to declare `async throw` functions.

Bottom line, given a call chain if `async` methods, where none of the functions suspend, is there a way to prevent the thread switches?

Comment: Why have async if all the code is sync? Seems like the intention is to use background “actors” if not there is no need for async sounds like the protocol should be adjusted.

Comment: @loremipsum yes, the real use cases are more complex, like the dependencies being resolved by distributed actors when testing.

Comment: If dependencies are being resolved by distributed actors when testing, then doesn’t that violate one of your question’s presumptions of “where none of the functions … suspend”?

Comment: @Rob the problem is related to the production code, like one in the code snippet, where no suspension happen. If suspension do indeed happen, as when testing the app, then the system works as intended.